# proof :A convergent sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

Theorem 1 :a convergent sequence is bounded (if $\alpha_n\longmapsto\alpha$, then there is a number $K$ such that :$|\alpha_n |<K$

My proof :

$\alpha_n\longmapsto\alpha$ that mean:

$\exists  N_1. |\alpha_n-\alpha|<1$ when $n\geq N_1$

(remarke :I chose $\epsilon=1$)

We know that$ |\alpha_n|=|\alpha _n - \alpha +\alpha|\leq|\alpha _n - \alpha|+\alpha<1+|\alpha| $

So if $n\geq N_1.|\alpha_n|  <|\alpha|+1 $   ($ *$)

If $n<N_1$:

We have this finite set $|\alpha_1|,|\alpha_2|,.......,||\alpha_{N_1 - 1}|$

In this set, exist a $|\alpha_r|$ whose is greater than or equal to each and every one of the set

i note that : $|\alpha_r|=k_1$

So $\forall n<N_1, \exists K_1.|\alpha_n |\leq k_1 $ ($**$)

So after ($*$) and ($**$) we can see $|\alpha_n |\leq k_1 $ and  $|\alpha_n|  <|\alpha|+1 $

And we know that $|\alpha_n |\leq k_1 <k_1 +1 $

Suppose $k_2=max(k_1+1,|\alpha|+1)$

So finally $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}. |\alpha_n|<k_2$

So all convergent sequence is bounded

Does my proof is true?

Any remarks or comments is welcome

Answer (score 4):

The proof is basically correct, but here are a couple of minor logical errors to be fixed:

- In $(**)$ the quantifiers are in the wrong order, it should be $\exists k_1 \forall n < N_1$...
- In the sentence starting "So after...", you wrote that $|\alpha_1| \le k_1$ **and** $|\alpha_n| < |\alpha| + 1$ but you should use **or** instead of **and**.

Comment: Okey thanks you .

Answer (score 1):

Although you proof is correct after applying Lee Mosher's comments, I believe there may be an easier way to prove it.

Consider the definition of a convergent sequence: $$\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists N\in\mathbb{N}  \;\text{s.t}\; \forall n\ge N, |a_{n}-a|<\varepsilon$$

Then:
$$ 
-\varepsilon<a_n-a<\varepsilon \implies a-\varepsilon<a_n<a+\varepsilon
$$
So the sequence is bounded for $n\ge N$, now for $n<N$, there are finitely many values so consider the set:
$$
A:=\{a_n:n<N\}
$$
Since the set is finite, it is bounded above by $max(A)$ and below by $min(A)$. So the sequence is bounded above by $max(max(A),a+\varepsilon)$ and below by $min(min(A),a-\varepsilon)$ so the sequence is bounded.